# How to make WebIOPi package in buildroot, getting buildroot error 127 when making

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, buildroot

I've tried to make a [WebIOPi](http://webiopi.trouch.com/) package for in buildroot for a raspberrypi 3.
But i get the following error from buildroot after the command make:

```
/bin/bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
package/pkg-generic.mk:206: recipe for target '/home/michael/biomedische/buildroot/output/build/WebIOPi-0.7.1/.stamp_configured' failed
make: *** [/home/michael/biomedische/buildroot/output/build/WebIOPi-0.7.1/.stamp_configured] Error 127
```

So I've made a directory WebIOPi in packages, made config.in and WebIOPi.mk files.
I first had problems with downloading the file from the original source, I solved this with a wetransfer link. The compiler then untars the file. But then I get the problem mentioned above.

It says I have to make a configure.in or configure.ac file, but i don't know where and how. Not much of information on the buildroot manual (it's more for a patch, not sure this is a patch). Is it maybe because I use autotools and need to make my own installing files?

In the files are:

-> config.in file:

```
config BR2_PACKAGE_WEBIOPI
    bool "WebIOPi"
    depends on BR2_PACKAGE_PYTHON
    help
      This is a package to install WebIOPi
      http://webiopi.trouch.com/
```

-> WebIOPi.mk file:

```
########################################################
#
# WebIOPi
#
########################################################
WEBIOPI_VERSION = 0.7.1
WEBIOPI_SOURCE = WebIOPi-$(WEBIOPI_VERSION).tar.gz
WEBIOPI_SITE = #wetransfer link
#WEBIOPI_SITE = http://sourceforge.net/projects/webiopi/files/
WEBIOPI_SITE_METHOD = wget
WEBIOPI_INSTALL_TARGET = YES
WEBIOPI_AUTORECONF = YES
WEBIOPI_CONF_OPTS += --with-python-support
WEBIOPI_LICENSE = LICENSE
WEBIOPI_DEPENDENCIES = python

$(eval $(autotools-package))
```

The WebIOPi has got a setup.py file. It works to install on my virtual ubuntu. If there's a better way to do this for buildroot, always welcome.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like WebIOPi was not created with the intention to be used on anything except Raspbian. It is not trivial to turn this into a Buildroot package (or yocto or .deb or any other distro).

To get started, take a look at the [Buildroot documentation for Python packages](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#_infrastructure_for_python_packages). You will need to set `WEBIOPI_SUBDIR = python` because the `setup.py` script it in the `python` subdirectory.

However, that only installs the python part. There are other bits and pieces that need to be installed, but the installation script `setup.sh` is not prepared for cross-building. So you need to look at this script and turn it into commands for [`WEBIOPI_POST_INSTALL_TARGET_HOOKS`](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#hooks).

If you are successful, or if you need more help, send a patch to [the Buildroot mailing list](http://lists.buildroot.org/mailman/listinfo/buildroot).